# Getting Room database "Invalid query argument" error while building project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room Database to store data in my application. But, trying to compile the project, I get the following error: "Invalid query argument". I tried to find the reason in the official documentation and also googling cause of this error, but it was all to no avail. **Please, could you help by explaining what this error is in general, what causes it and what I need to fix in the project?**

**Exact error message**

```
C:\Users\***\ParsedDatabase.java:10: error: Invalid query argument: int. It must be a class or an interface.
public final class ParsedDatabase {
             ^
```

**Model - ParsedDatabase (Room Database entity, class with problem)**

```
@Entity(tableName = "parsed_database")
data class ParsedDatabase(
    @PrimaryKey()
    val id: Int = 1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "app_config")
    val appConfigSection: HashMap<String, String>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "loans")
    val loansList: ArrayList<Offer>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cards")
    val cardsList: ArrayList<ArrayList<Offer>>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "credits")
    val creditsList: ArrayList<Offer>,
) {

    enum class AppConfigKeys {
        app_config,
        user_term_html,
        extra_field_,
    }

    enum class LoansAndCreditsKeys {
        loans,
        credits,
    }

    enum class CardsKeys {
        cards,
    }

}
```

**Dao class (I attach just in case)**

```
@Dao
interface LocalDatabaseDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun save(parsedDatabase: ParsedDatabase)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM parsed_database WHERE id = :id")
    fun load(id: Int = 1): ParsedDatabase?

    @Delete
    fun delete(parsedDatabase: ParsedDatabase)

    @Delete(entity = ParsedDatabase::class)
    fun delete(id: Int = 1)
}
```

**Database class**

```
@Database(entities = [ParsedDatabase::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class LocalDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getLocalDatabaseDao(): LocalDatabaseDao
}
```

Comment: Try removing `fun delete(id: Int = 1)` from your DAO.

Comment: @CommonsWare It actually worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```kotlin
    @Delete(entity = ParsedDatabase::class)
    fun delete(id: Int = 1)
```

I do not think that Room knows what to do with this. If you need that operation, you could try:

```kotlin
    @Query("DELETE FROM parsed_database WHERE id = :id")
    fun delete(id: Int = 1)
```